Why did Vandermonde become interested in algebraic problems?
I recently became interested in a person named Vandermonde when I posted a question on this site about the history of determinants and read the answers and comments. He was a person who loved music and became interested in mathematics at a late age. Why did he become interested in algebra among all the mathematics? Is there a motivation or background that led you to be particularly interested in determinants in algebra? I know that Vandermonde was interested in chess problems in relation to mathematics, and that this contributed to the development of knot theory. But other than that, I'm curious about Vandermonde's motivation and background for becoming interested in algebra.

Have you read Vandermonde's biography at MacTutor? It states "He pursued a music career and he only turned to mathematics when he was 35 years old. It was Fontaine des Bertins whose enthusiasm for mathematics rubbed off on Vandermonde." Apparently four papers comprise his entire mathematical output; details of the papers are discussed at MacTutor.

Jacqueline Hecht, "Un exemple de multidisciplinarité: Alexandre Vandermonde (1735-1796)." Population, Vol. 26, No. 4, Jul. 1971, pp. 641-676, portraits Vandermonde as a multidisciplinary researcher who was able to pursue his keen interest (vif penchant) in mathematics when he came into his father's inheritance after the death of his half-brother in 1762.

Interesting side note: Bernard Ycart, "A case of mathematical eponymy: the Vandermonde determinant." Revue d'histoire des mathématiques, Vol. 19, No. 1, p. 43-77 (also: arXiv preprint arXiv:1204.4716, 2012).

@njuffa Hello, Thank you for your comment! I'll read the linked article!!

For discussion regarding Vandermonde's work in music theory see: Gessele, C. M. (1994). Base d'harmonie: A Scene from Eighteenth-Century French Music Theory. Journal of the Royal Musical Association, 119(1), 60-90.
